# Почему не подключается usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я пытаюсь изучать MVVM. Решил создать тестовый проект сразу с правильной структурой. Вот для начала у меня есть папка Views. В ней я отдельно описал главное окно (MVVMSample.Views.MainWindow) и главное представление как usercontrol (MVVMSample.Views.MainView). Потом я как в каком то найденном в интернете примере пишу в App.xaml.cs следующее:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

using MVVMSample.Views;

namespace MVVMSample
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = new MainWindow();
            var view = new MainView();
            window.Content = view;
            window.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

А в App.xaml оставил только:

```
<Application x:Class="MVVMSample.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"/>
```

Тут я пока еще не создал ни Model ни ViewModel, только View чтобы хоть можно было запустить приложение. Но вот проблема у меня вообще не отображается MainView в окне. Т.е. чтобы я в MainView не кинул (кнопки, контент всякий...) у меня пустое окно. В чем дело???

Comment: не мудрите, укажите юзер контрол в xaml основного окна, а не window.Content = view;

Comment: @vitidev это называется не мудрить, а четко следовать паттерну, даже когда это приносит несколько больше дополнительного кода.

Comment: Паттерн MVVM не требует того, что вы указали. Более того, суть паттерна MVVM в том, что вы управляете DataContext, а что рисуется уже решает сам вид. Так что ваша строка window.Content = view; это ваше личное пожелание, а не следование паттерну.

Comment: @vitidev просто так было в том примере который я нашел. А как вы предлагаете тогда задавать ViewModel для View? Для этого же надо сначала получить где то объект этого самого View, а если он будет задан в xaml-разметке то я даже не знаю...

Comment: Задавайте вьюмодел окну в котором этот вью и он его автоматом получит.

Comment: @vitidev мелочь, но все же: MainWindow где лучше объявлять? Мне все же кажется что во Views он лишний, но и отдельно его бросать не хочется. Может создать еще какую нибудь папочку (неймспейс) типа WIndows и в нее?

Comment: Это на любителя. Я вот оставляю в корне как логический корневой элемент.

Comment: Покамест с точки зрения MVVM всё хорошо, проблем не вижу. Попробую проэкспериментировать.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. Покажите ваш UserControl

Comment: @VladD уже все заработало.

Comment: @DarkByte: А в чём была проблема?

Comment: @DarkByte: У нас тут на сайте куча похожих примеров. Поищите по «`protected override void OnStartup`».